# Samsung Galaxy S5 ROM for Micromax Bolt A068

Tags: rom

Where can I find a Samsung Galaxy S5 ROM for Micromax Bolt A068? If an S5 ROM is not available, then please provide a download link for S4 or Note 3 for my device.

Comment: @RossC, Dan You probably shouldn't be even suggesting that. He wants to flash a ROM that isn't even compatible with his device.

Comment: @geffchang I misread it, not sure what he was thinking! My apologies, though if he couldn't find THAT rom, he had other devices!! I'll delete it!

Answer (score 1):

Do not attempt to flash a ROM for a different device (e.g. Samsung Galaxy S5, S4, Note 3) that is not intended for your device (Micromax Bolt A068). It will not work, and can possibly brick/destroy your phone.

A Google search for custom ROMs for your phone does not return a lot of results. So, it's safe to assume that there aren't a lot of custom ROMs for your phone. Even an [XDA post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/aokp/general/custom-micromax-bolt-a068-rom-t2808004) remains unanswered.